# Previous data auto insert when browser reloading in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have some data `input` area.Here is my file.

Here is my **db.php:**

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=task', $username, $password);
    echo "Connection Successfull";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: Database connection");
}

?>
```

And my **index.php** is:

```
<?php 
    include "db.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is title</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap1">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="text" name="name" required>  Username</br></br>
            <input type="email" name="email" required>  Email</br></br>
            <input type="text" name="website" required>  Website</br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php
        $username = $_POST['name'];
        $emailadd = $_POST['email'];
        $webadd   = $_POST['website'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,email,website) VALUES ('$username','$emailadd','$webadd')";
        if(empty($username) || empty($emailadd) || empty($webadd)){
            echo "Please input all field";
        }
        else{
            if ($db->query($sql)) {
                echo "Inserted!";
            }
            else{
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
        $db = null;

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When i first go to **index.php** page then it's showing some notice.

> Notice: Undefined index: name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\techmasters\begin\index.php on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\techmasters\begin\index.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Undefined index: website in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\techmasters\begin\index.php on line 23

but if i input any data then it going to be inserted fine.My problem is that if i reload the browser then previous inserted data going to inserted again.How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because, you are not checking whether form is submitted or not.

On every page request, data is getting inserted, add a check.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && ! empty($_POST['name'])) {
 $username = $_POST['name'];
 $emailadd = $_POST['email'];
 $webadd   = $_POST['website'];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,email,website) VALUES ('$username','$emailadd','$webadd')";
 if (empty($username) || empty($emailadd) || empty($webadd)){
  echo "Please input all field";
 }
 else{
  if ($db->query($sql)) {
   echo "Inserted!";
  }
  else{
   echo "Error";
  }
 }
 $db = null;
 $_POST = NULL;
}
?>
```

This will ensure that database insert will be done only in case of form submit.

**EDIT:**

> If you submit a form to same page and then reload the page, it will
>   ask you to resubmit the form. Either change method to get and check
>   for duplicity or submit the form to another file (move form submit
>   code to other file and set it as form action).

Comment: isn't `$_POST`  always available?

Comment: `$_POST` is always set, might as well just use `!empty` or maybe just say that particular post fields that the OP's checking are initially empty

Comment: @SwarajGiri, you are correct. `$_POST` is a super global variable and is always available. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['name'] && $_POST['name']))` No need to use `empty`. `if` will suffice.

Comment: using if(isset($_POST)){ }  is enough to make this working.

Comment: @Pupil your code should be correct as if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']))

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud, what is the error you are getting.

Comment: @Pupil I am not getting any error.I see when browser reloading then its popup a window and resend or cancle.But i do not want this pop window.I want simple reload and do not insert any data when i reloading.

Comment: That is a browser property. If you submit a form to same page and then reload the page, it will ask you to resubmit the form. Either change method to get and check for duplicity or submit the form to another file (move form submit code to other file and set it as form action).

Comment: @Pupil sorry i am getting this error: 
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\techmasters\begin\index.php on line 21

Comment: @Chonchol Mahmud just change the condition to  if (isset($_POST)) {  ***** }

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page it's asking for form re-submission. When you click on resend then it will post all data again and inserted in database. To overcome this issue you can use jquery.

Try this code :

html file :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>This is title</title>
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap1">
            <form method="POST" id="frm" action="">
                <input type="text" name="name" required>  Username</br></br>
                <input type="email" name="email" required>  Email</br></br>
                <input type="text" name="website" required>  Website</br></br>
                <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
<script>
$(".sub").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("test.php",$("#frm").serialize(),function(data){
       if(data == "Inserted!") {
           //You can reload your page here
        } else {
           //Display error message.
        }
     });
});
</script>

     </body>
    </html>
```

You php code (test.php) :

```
<?php
include "db.php";
if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != "") {
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $emailadd = $_POST['email'];
    $webadd   = $_POST['website'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,email,website) VALUES ('$username','$emailadd','$webadd')";
    if(empty($username) || empty($emailadd) || empty($webadd)){
          echo "Please input all field";
    } else {
           if ($db->query($sql)) {
              echo "Inserted!";
           }
           else{
              echo "Error";
           }
     }
     $db = null;
     exit;
}

?>
```

Don't forget to add jquery file in your html.